# createGlobalStyle does not render children - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-component, react-css-modules

Not displaying the output whenever trying on http://localhost:3000/
[image: Showing warning]

Not able to understand how to resolve this issue and print desired output

Expecting to print a black box on the browser since written in css code for "theme.colos.bg: #000"

Comment: Show the code please

Answer (score 1):

The `createGlobalStyle` creates a component that injects/sets global CSS defaults but ***doesn't*** take and render any children. It's a standalone component that is rendered alongside your app code/JSX.

[createGlobalStyle](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle)

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  ... default CSS ...
`;

// later in your app

<React.Fragment>
  <GlobalStyle />
  ... your app components here
</React.Fragment>
```